# Error while using lapply() function to perform logistic regression (undefined columns selected)

Tags: r, dataframe

So the data is retrieved here https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00497/divorce.rar

When I run the code to perform logistic regression, it shows an error. But it runs perfectly on others R program. Is there anything that I have missed out?

> set.seed(123)

> divorce = read.csv("C://Users//User//Documents//Y2S3//Predictive Modelling//divorce//divorce.csv")

> dim(divorce)

Outcome: [1] 170   1

> summary(divorce)

Outcome:
Atr1.Atr2.Atr3.Atr4.Atr5.Atr6.Atr7.Atr8.Atr9.Atr10.Atr11.Atr12.Atr13.Atr14.Atr15.Atr16.Atr17.Atr18.Atr19.Atr20.Atr21.Atr22.Atr23.Atr24.Atr25.Atr26.Atr27.Atr28.Atr29.Atr30.Atr31.Atr32.Atr33.Atr34.Atr35.Atr36.Atr37.Atr38.Atr39.Atr40.Atr41.Atr42.Atr43.Atr44.Atr45.Atr46.Atr47.Atr48.Atr49.Atr50.Atr51.Atr52.Atr53.Atr54.Class

Length:170

Class :character

Mode  :character

> colnames(divorce)

Outcome:
[1] "Atr1.Atr2.Atr3.Atr4.Atr5.Atr6.Atr7.Atr8.Atr9.Atr10.Atr11.Atr12.Atr13.Atr14.Atr15.Atr16.Atr17.Atr18.Atr19.Atr20.Atr21.Atr22.Atr23.Atr24.Atr25.Atr26.Atr27.Atr28.Atr29.Atr30.Atr31.Atr32.Atr33.Atr34.Atr35.Atr36.Atr37.Atr38.Atr39.Atr40.Atr41.Atr42.Atr43.Atr44.Atr45.Atr46.Atr47.Atr48.Atr49.Atr50.Atr51.Atr52.Atr53.Atr54.Class"

> sapply(divorce,class)

Outcome:
Atr1.Atr2.Atr3.Atr4.Atr5.Atr6.Atr7.Atr8.Atr9.Atr10.Atr11.Atr12.Atr13.Atr14.Atr15.Atr16.Atr17.Atr18.Atr19.Atr20.Atr21.Atr22.Atr23.Atr24.Atr25.Atr26.Atr27.Atr28.Atr29.Atr30.Atr31.Atr32.Atr33.Atr34.Atr35.Atr36.Atr37.Atr38.Atr39.Atr40.Atr41.Atr42.Atr43.Atr44.Atr45.Atr46.Atr47.Atr48.Atr49.Atr50.Atr51.Atr52.Atr53.Atr54.Class
"character"

> col_fac = c("Atr1","Atr2","Atr3","Atr4","Atr5","Atr6","Atr7","Atr8","Atr9","Atr10",
> +"Atr11","Atr12","Atr13","Atr14","Atr15","Atr16","Atr17","Atr18","Atr19","Atr20",
> +"Atr21","Atr22","Atr23","Atr24","Atr25","Atr26","Atr27","Atr28","Atr29","Atr30",
> +"Atr31","Atr32","Atr33","Atr34","Atr35","Atr36","Atr37","Atr38","Atr39","Atr40",
> +"Atr41","Atr42","Atr43","Atr44","Atr45","Atr46","Atr47","Atr48","Atr49","Atr50",
> +"Atr51","Atr52","Atr53","Atr54","Class")

> divorce[col_fac] = lapply(divorce[col_fac],factor)

Outcome: Error in `[.data.frame`(divorce, col_fac) : undefined columns selected)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Specifically, please do not provide either your code or data as screenshots.  Please use `dput()` for data and paste your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue is that you read a file that is separated by ";" and not ",". The `sep = ";"` will solve the issue.

```r
# downloaded and extracted from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00497/divorce.rar
divorce <- read.csv("./divorce.csv", sep = ";")
dim(divorce)
summary(divorce)
colnames(divorce)
sapply(divorce,class)
col_fac = c("Atr1","Atr2","Atr3","Atr4","Atr5","Atr6","Atr7","Atr8","Atr9","Atr10",
            "Atr11","Atr12","Atr13","Atr14","Atr15","Atr16","Atr17","Atr18","Atr19","Atr20",
            "Atr21","Atr22","Atr23","Atr24","Atr25","Atr26","Atr27","Atr28","Atr29","Atr30", 
            "Atr31","Atr32","Atr33","Atr34","Atr35","Atr36","Atr37","Atr38","Atr39","Atr40", 
            "Atr41","Atr42","Atr43","Atr44","Atr45","Atr46","Atr47","Atr48","Atr49","Atr50", 
            "Atr51","Atr52","Atr53","Atr54","Class")

divorce[col_fac] = lapply(divorce[col_fac],factor)
```

### less error prone version using dplyr

The following will `mutate` your dataset by applying the function `as.factor` `across` those variables `where` the function `is.numeric` returns `TRUE`.
Note that the functions passed within `across` and `where` do not get the usual parenthesis.

```r
library(dplyr)
divorce <- read.csv("./divorce.csv", sep = ";") %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.factor))
glimpse(divorce)
```

For detailed info on mutate across, type `?across` in R Console.